# Passing data to a specific ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

The picture is just an example...

[image]

So basically I want to pass data from *RED* to *BLUE* but i have to go through *GREEN*.. is there a way to just pass the data straight to *BLUE* without it having to go through *GREEN*?

What I'm doing now is the *conventional method* of passing the data to *GREEN* then having *GREEN* read it and pass it on to *BLUE*

But my app has a lot of `ViewControllers` and I wish to be able to pass it straight to the final page (*BLUE* page) is there a way?  Sorry I'm new to the Swift

Comment: Check out this answer. I couldn't explain it better than that.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/7188985

Answer (score 1):

If you try to pass data from _Red to _Blue, without _Green - it about bad architecture, becouse if something changed in logic of app, and you need to changed flow of controllers - you will feel a lot of headache...

You can wrap your data in object and pass through or you can make `DataController` which will be manage your data, and your `ViewController's` will be `get\set` it by `Datacontroller` interface

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple swift class e.g **Sharedclass** to set a variable and then get the value of the variable from the same **Sharedclass**. Example is given below

```
import Foundation

class SharedClass {
  static let sharedInstance = SharedClass()
  var phoneNumber = ""
}
```

To set the variable

```
SharedClass.sharedInstance.phoneNumber = "123456"
```

To get the variable

```
BLUEViewController.phoneNumber = SharedClass.sharedInstance.phoneNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push your navigationController directly to one of your viewControllers.  Try this;

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let blueController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BlueViewController") as? BluewViewController {
        blueController.passedData = passedData
        navigationController?.pushViewController(blueController, animated: true)
    }
```

Or you can just present it too. Instead of pushing in navigation controller.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let blueController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BlueViewController") as? BluewViewController {
        blueController.passedData = passedData
        present(blueController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: urmm but the app flow has to still be RED GREEN BLUE.. i just want to pass certain data from RED straight to BLUE..

Comment: Well, i don't think there is a straight way of doing this. Because views must be loaded for filling their properties. You can wrap your data in an object maybe. But views will still needs to be loaded.